# How to check crash log of a specific case for android signed apk

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk

I'm using react native and followed their website's guide on releasing signed apk. But I'm facing this really weird case right now where:

- My signed apk is installed on more than 20 devices for beta testing
- They are distributed manually as apk files internally using diawi.com services and email blasts (which user then can just download as a random apk file and install the downloaded file manually, not via playstore)
- It has been running on those devices everyday for the past week without failing once
- Suddenly it started crashing on just 1 particular device, a samsung S8 to be exact
- The user has tried uninstalling and reinstalling but problem persisted

My question is, for this very specific case, how do I check the crash log and diagnose the problem?

Comment: I would try adding a crash tracking solution, like [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/)

Comment: some devices restrict background processes, so take a look on your background proceeses if you have any, and also check runtime permission feature.. you are accessing data before you check permission, it will crash on release apk..

Comment: @SagarChavada background processes are not available for React Native to begin with and I'm not importing any native modules that does that so it shouldn't be the case.. if it's permission problem like you said, it would also be weird because this user has been using this app for a while... but I'll definitely check that, thanks! :D